# How to get phone number type label from given phone number in android

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number

I tried to print Contact name(Eg. "Jose") & Contact phone number type value(Eg. "Home","Work",etc.,) from phone contact for given particular phone number(Eg. "9600515852")

for this i used bellow code. but i can able get Contact name only. i am getting app crash when i am trying to get the phone number type.

Please guide me.

```
String number = getContactName(this, "9600515852");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),number,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

private String getContactName(Context context, String number) {
String TAG ="" ;
String name = null, label=null;
int type=0;

// define the columns I want the query to return
String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID };

// encode the phone number and build the filter URI
   Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));

// query time
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);

        if(cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                name =      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
               // type = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Contact Not Found @ " + number);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return name+" - "+number;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.TYPE));
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

instead of

```
name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

In My case, On button click getting contact information from Contacts app is like this. And it is working

Call an Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Handle the result

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case (1):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();

                Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);

                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    String resultedPhoneNum = pop.getContactNumber(id, MainActiv.this);
                    String resultedName=pop.getContactName(name, MainActiv.this);

                    contactName.setText(resultedName);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well the correct approach is to include the **Phone.TYPE** in your Projection query. It contains only **DISPLAY_NAME** and**ID** and it crashes as there is no field as "type" included in your query.

This will definitely solve your issue.